# Better way to access variables across prototype methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I often use the pattern of a main JavaScript constructor function and adding methods to its prototype object so they can be called intuitively by the user, for example:

```
function Slideshow(options) {
    this.options = options
    this.slideshow = $('#slideshow')
    //more variables here
}

Slideshow.method1 = function () {
    this.slideshow.addClass('test') // do something with slideshow variable
};

Slideshow.method2 = function () {
    // another method
};
```

The one thing that really bugs me about this pattern is how in order to make variables accessible across all prototype methods, I have to add "this" in front of each variable inside the constructor function. It's a major pain, and I can't help but think there's a more elegant way to do this.

If I forgo using the prototype object and just add the methods as instance methods, I know I can't get around this problem, but I like the efficiency? and self encapsulating nature of this pattern. Any other suggestions for a better pattern? Thanks!

Comment: Please look at my edits as they follow JavaScript best practice.  Please capitalize your constructor functions.

Comment: Also, don't replace the prototype with another object, you will end up overwriting things that need to be kept.

Answer (score 3):

> It's a major pain

No, it's really not. Every single JavaScript developer uses this syntax. If you were in Ruby or Python, you'd use `self.`, in PHP you'd use `$this->`. Some languages like C++ don't require any special decorator, but JavaScript does.

> and I can't help but think there's a more elegant way to do this.

No, there isn't.

This is JavaScript's syntax, you cannot change it, and you cannot work around it. If you want to access a property of `this`, you need `this.` before the property name. Otherwise, you're talking about global variables.

If you want a different syntax, consider a different language like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which compiles to JavaScript.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  This really isn't a pain to write `this` before accessing properties on your object.  Every OOP language follows this rule to refer to an object method or property, whether it's `self.`, `this.`, `parent::`, or the name of a variable holding your object.

Answer (score 0):

meager has pretty much summed things up if you're talking about accessing public instance properties or methods.  You have to use `this` in front of it as that's just how the language works.

But, if you have private instance properties or methods, you can define those as local variables inside the constructor and you can access them without `this`.

```
function slideshow(options) {
    // no need to resave the options arguments as they can be used
    // directly from the argument variable

    // define a per-instance private variable that other methods defined
    // within the constructor can use directly without the use of `this`
    var theShow = $(options.selector || '#slideshow');

    // define public methods
    this.method1 = function() {
        // can access private instance variable here without this in front of it
        theShow.addClass('test');
    }

    this.method2 = function() {
        theShow.addClass(options.decoaration);
    }
}
```

This general design pattern is described here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Practically speaking, this works because the constructor function with the public methods declared inside it creates a closure that lasts for the duration of the object lifetime so the local variables in the constructor become per-instance variables accessible only from the functions declared within the constructor.